# Rogue rows being removed from cataloginventory_stock_status

Tags: magento2, stock, stock-status

We have around 180,000 products and are having issues with salable quantity not matching quantity.

We've narrowed it down to an issue with the table "cataloginventory_stock_status"

When we reindex cataloginventory_stock, this table is populated correctly with 180,000 rows.

However this table is being reduced by about 1,000 rows every 2-3 minutes.

If I wait 10 minutes we are around 172,000 rows.

I've turned off the crons but this is still happening.

I've no clue what would be causing rows to drop off.

Has anyone seen this issue or have any tips on identifying what exactly is happening?

Comment: We are on Magento 2.3.1 if that helps.

Comment: I ended up killing off the cron related processes.  The table is now stabilized and rows aren't being removed.  So I'm thinking now it is in fact a cron related issue, even though it was disabled it's possible the crons were still working on it in the background with a long process.